# php link from a page to the same page seo

Tags: html, seo

**HELLO**

Let's say I have an home page with 200 list items on it. each list item contain picture and 2 links.

one link go to a unique page that will show more details about the item

the second link go to the home page that display the 200 items.

what i am saying is that on the home page i will have 200 links leading to the home page again, making a crawler loop.

how bad is it?
should i prevent this for seo purposes?

www.mydomain.com/home-page/
---------------------------contain the follow

```
<div class = "item" id = "item1">
 <img src = "/pictures/my_pictures/item1.jpg">
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/item1/"> 
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/home-page/">
</div>
<div class = "item" id = "item2">
 <img src = "/pictures/my_pictures/item2.jpg">
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/item2/"> 
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/home-page/">
</div> 
 <div class = "item" id = "item3">
 <img src = "/pictures/my_pictures/item3.jpg">
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/item3/"> 
 <a href = "www.mydomain.com/home-page/">
</div>
```

.....197 more items

Comment: show us some code man!! that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue regarding SEO here. No worry. Google does not care about internal links. You can do what you want.